# using selenium based python code on azure server

Tags: javascript, python, azure, selenium

Selemium uses browser to open the page and get content. But on my azure server(command line based) I could not have chrome or firefox. So what is the alternative to use python based selenium code on azure server.

I looked at http://phantomjs.org/ a headless browser. But I guess it is javascript so I would require to convert python code in JS.

Is there any other better alternative?

code snippet:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def getVideoTrend(self, item):
    driver.get(item['link'])
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yvp-main'))
    self.yahoo_video_trend = []
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yvp-main'):
        print "Processing link  - ", item['link']
        trend = item
        trend['video_link'] = s.find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        print s.find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        self.yahoo_video_trend.append(trend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) for your browsing needs and [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for  parsing

Comment: @user464224: thanks, but youtube, google, yahoo does not give entire html using requests, so this does not help

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the alternative to use python based selenium code on azure
>   server.

May I know whether you are using Azure Web App? Per my understanding, Azure Web App does not allow us to install the custom software on the server. So in this case you may want to use a virtual machine instead. Windows based virtual machines have GUI pre-enabled, so you only need to use remote desktop to login to the server and install a browser (if you don’t want to use the default IE). For a Linux server, you can install a desktop and then install a browser as well. Please refer to http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm.aspx to see if this instruction is helpful.